# wpf checkbox label as button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, checkbox

In WPF I would like the label in the CheckBox to behave like a button, so when I toggle the checkbox to ON, I would like the label to change to a button, and when I toggle the checkbox to OFF, then button go change back to label.

Here is what I have so far

```
<CheckBox Margin="2,0,2,0"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSteps}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Height="32"
                            FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderCheckBoxStyle}">
    <CheckBox.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Steps" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontFamily="Lucida Sans" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: you can add another button and show/hide it binding to that check box

Answer (score 2):

In your Checkbox.Content, create a StackPanel with both TextBlock and Button.
Then, You can bind your TextBlock.Visibilty and Button.Visibilty to "IsSteps" with triggers and setters.

```
<CheckBox Margin="2,0,2,0"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSteps}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Height="32"
                            FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderCheckBoxStyle}">
    <CheckBox.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Steps" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontFamily="Lucida Sans" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSteps}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                <TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Button>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSteps}" Value="False">
                               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                           </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                <Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

Now their Visibility property depends on IsSteps from your DataContext object, so when one appears and other one disappears.